# jsdoc for the imported class

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea, jsdoc, jsdoc3

I have file lib.js:

```
/** @module lib */

/** @constructor */
var Clazz = function() {
   this.x = 12;
};
exports.Clazz = Clazz;
```

and test.js

```
/** @exports lib */
var lib = require('./lib');
var inst = new lib.Clazz();
inst.x;
```

I can not get the documentation for the "x" variable in the file test.js. If I import the class otherwise, all works:

```
/** @exports lib */
var Clazz = require('./lib').Clazz;
var inst = new Clazz();
inst.x;
```

I use intellij idea 13 for develop.